# mailForm not sending mail locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mail-form

I want to create a simple contact form where the user can send a message to a specific mail adress (mine) just by writing his name, email and message. I'm using mailForm to do it but it's not working and i don't know why, i need some help... I obviously looked previous subjects about this but it didn't help me.

Here is my code:

**Model**

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name, validate: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
  attribute :email, validate: /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/i
  attribute :message, validate: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  attribute :nickname, captcha: true

  def headers
    { subject: "My Contact Form",
      to: "mypersonalemail@gmail.com",
      from: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contacts_params)
    @contact.request = request
    if @contact.deliver
      flash.now[:notice] = 'Merci pour votre message, je reviens vers vous très prochainement !'
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Votre message n'a pas pu être envoyé, veuillez vérifier les données saisies"
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def contacts_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :message)
  end
end
```

As it's a gmail adress i have this in
**development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'https://localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'mypersonalemail@gmail.com',
    password:             'mypersonalpassword',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Everything is like working fine, especially when i enter this in the console:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 4086
Loading development environment (Rails 6.0.3.3)
irb(main):001:0> c = Contact.new(name: 'Nobody', email: 'nobody@email.com', message: 'testestest')
=> #<Contact:0x00007fe140203e00 @name="Nobody", @email="nobody@email.com", @message="testestest">
irb(main):002:0> c.valid?
=> true
irb(main):003:0> c.deliver
  Rendering /home/slegrez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mail_form-1.8.1/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb
  Rendered /home/slegrez/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/mail_form-1.8.1/lib/mail_form/views/mail_form/contact.erb (Duration: 22.8ms | Allocations: 1843)
MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 62.8ms
Delivered mail 5fc8ed66de0be_ff62b269f0d999015752@DESKTOP-DQRGQT4.mail (890.4ms)
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 15:51:34 +0200
From: Nobody <nobody@email.com>
To: mypersonalemail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5fc8ed66de0be_ff62b269f0d999015752@DESKTOP-DQRGQT4.mail>
Subject: My Contact Form
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h4 style="text-decoration:underline">My Contact Form</h4>


  <p><b>Name:</b>
  Nobody</p>

  <p><b>Email:</b>
  nobody@email.com</p>

  <p><b>Message:</b>
  testestest</p>


=> true
```

After that, i don't get any mail, even in the spams. I mean, c.valid? is given true so i really don't understand why it's not sending anything. I checked the email adress and the password, no mistakes. I disabled gmail security on less secured applications because i received a notification from gmail (so it means that's they catched something no ?).
Well, please, help :(

Comment: I think the problem is not in `mail_form` gem, it is not responsible for sending emails it just nicely wrapper. However your issue is in your `config.action_mailer`. How did you configure it, some guide in google docs or?

Comment: To be honest i didn't config action mailer at all. I kept everything that is already there... Like for example `raise_delivery_errors = false`, `perform_caching = false`, and what i've linked previously

Comment: `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` but this one seems like you removed personal data, and in your local repo there is real data or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "personal data", the email adress and the password ? If yes, then yes, it is written in the repo

Comment: well it seems I understand. So you just entered your password and email into `config/development.rb` and want emails to be sent from your name, right?
this won't work

Comment: Not from my name but to my name.
I want people to complete a form and when they'll submit the form, it will send an email to my email adress. Maybe i wasn't very clear :/

Comment: but in order to send something by mail, you need to configure provider, currently it is not configured. take a look for example [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) and ruby library [wrapper](https://github.com/HashNuke/mailgun#sending-mail-using-actionmailer)

Comment: Does Sendgrid with Herok can handle this ? I tried but i didn't have any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

In your `config/environments/development.rb`  ?

In order to rails send emails locally you need to add this in your development environment.

Comment: thank you so much it finally works ! 3 days of search for this only line, thank you thank you thank you :D